# Error with Spring gem when I try to start rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I'm working on a project that was started by someone else. When I try to start the rails console I get the following error:

> /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in
>   `block in setup': You have already activated spring 1.3.6, but your
>   Gemfile requires spring 1.3.3. Prepending`bundle exec` to your
>   command may solve this.

I've run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and `bundle exec rake db:seed`, there were also no problems with `bundle install` - Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: Well, why don't you run `bundle exec rails c`? :)

Comment: Just tried that now, I get the same error message.

Comment: Just to be sure – did you close all your terminal sessions, and then after reopening the terminal tried that command?

Comment: Yep, I did that too :)

Comment: Well, try rm -f Gemfile.lock and then repeat the steps.

Comment: Is that removing Gemfile.lock?

Comment: It works! Ran through all the setup commands as well using `bundle exec` and console is working now. If you put this in an answer I'd be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was found out in comments, the solution is to remove `Gemfile.lock` and reinstall the bundle.